# Issue with activity called with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, exit

I want to finish my app calling the first activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and finishing it. However, when it finishes, the app restarts automatically, and goes directly to Activity 2.

Why? Isn't the stack of activity supposed to be empty after finishing an activity called with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`?

My stack is  Activity2>(more activities)>Activity1.

In Activity2

```
Intent exit_intent=new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
exit_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
exit_intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
context.startActivity(exit_intent);
```

In Activity1

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {           
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `finish()` is being called properly in Activity1? I'm getting the feeling it's not, because:

1. I'm not sure where that `if` statement goes inside your Activity. It should be in `onNewIntent`.
2. If you are making that `if` statement inside the `onNewIntent` method, it's **still** wrong. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) specify that `getIntent()` will always return the original intent that started the Activity, unless you call `setIntent()`.

To conclude, maybe something else is getting called in your Activity1 (can't tell without the full code) that starts Activity2 instead of finishing.

If what I described is not the case, and your activity stack indeed looks like Activity2 > Activity1 like the others have described yes, it will not work. Just call `finish()` in Activity2?

Comment: Yes, it' called, and the system goes back to Android menu properly. But it restarts and goes to Activity2...

Comment: You were right, something else was called after finishing Activity1 that starts Activity2. I thought no code was executed after calling `finish()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From the javadoc:

*If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.*

CLEAR_TOP will wipe out all Activities **ABOVE** `Activity1`: if `Activity2` is below `Activity1` then once `Activity1` finishes you will see `Activity2`.

Comment: UpVote for the explanation apart from javadoc

Comment: It's not, I've got Activity2>(more activities)>Activity1

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

So it doesn't clear the entire activity stack, only any other activities that were on top of an old instance of the activity being launched.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right but are you catching the intent inside onNewIntent method of your first activity? also activity 2 should be launched after activity 1 in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

From Intent doc:

```
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created.